# How to Render Table Row from an API

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs

I have a list of object in an array like this

```
const data =[
  {
      "course": "Advanced Diploma of Accounting",
      "provider": [
          {
              "school": "Gold Coast Learning Centre PTy LTD as Trustee for GCLC Unit Trust",
              "duration": "32"
          },
          {
              "school": "Business Institute of Australia Pty LTD",
              "duration": "52"
          }
        ]
  },
  {
   
      "course": "Advanced Diploma of Business",
      "provider": [
          {
              "school": "AUSTRALIA ACADEMY INTERNATIONAL PTY LTD",
              "duration": "52"
          },
          {
              "school": "Australian College of Digital Technologies Pty Ltd",
              "duration": "22"
          }
        ]
  },
  {
      "course": "Advanced Diploma of Information Technology",
      "provider": [
          {
              "school": "GRIFFIN COLLEGE OF MANAGEMENT & TECHNOLOGY PTY. LTD.",
              "duration": "104"
          },
          {
              "school": "OHS Media Services Pty Ltd",
              "duration": "69"
          }
        ]
  }
]
```

I have code Which makes the table and the code looks something like this

```
function buildtable(data) {
  const [{course,level,provider}] = data
  console.log(data)

 tablebody.innerHTML = provider.map(item=> {
   return `
    <tr>
      <td>${course}</td>
      <td>${item.provider}</td>
    </tr>
   `
 }).join('')

}
```

It renders table something like this in the DOM

| Course | Provider | Duration |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Advanced Diploma of Accounting | Gold Coast Learning | 32 |
| Advanced Diploma of Accounting | Business Institute | 52 |

But I want something Like this

| Course | Provider | Duration |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Advanced Diploma of Accounting | Gold Coast Learning | 32 |
| Advanced Diploma of Accounting | Business Institute | 52 |
| Advanced Diploma of Information Technology | OHS Media Service | 69 |
| Advanced Diploma of Information Techonology | Griffin College | 52 |
| Advanced diploma of Business | Australian College | 22 |

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this, works for me:

```
data.map((course) => {
  course.provider.map(({ school, duration }) => {
    return (tablebody.innerHTML += `
      <tr>
        <td>${course.course}</td>
        <td>${school}</td>
        <td>${duration}</td>
      </tr>
    `);
  });
});
```

So we map through the courses, then the provider within them and cause each loop to render the course name out each time it shows the provider items since it's the same course name for each inside. Then we use += on the innerHTML so it can append each item as it loops through.